# evaluating integral over graph of semicircles with parameterization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

Evaluate the path integral of $f(x, y) = y$ over the graph of the semicircle

$y = \sqrt{1-x^2}, -1 \leq x \leq 1$

solution:

$\vec{C}(t) = (cos(t), sin(t))$

$\vec{C}'(t) = (-sin(t), cos(t))$

$||\vec{C}(t)'|| = 1$

$\int_{C} f ds = \int_{0}^{\pi} sin(t)dt = -cos(t)|_{0}^{\pi} = -(-1-1) = 2$

---

Could someone explain the solution please. How they get "$\vec{C}(t) = (cos(t), sin(t))$"

what's the use of "$||\vec{C}(t)'|| = 1$"

where does $0 \leq t \leq \pi$ come from?

Comment: $C$ is the parametric equation of a circle. They integrate from $0$ to $\pi$ since they want the hemicircle. $f=y=\sin\theta$ due to the polar coordinates substitution. The length of the derivative comes from the change of coordinates. Basically you can regard this as a line integral, or as going to polar coordinates and then solving the double (now single) integral. Additionally it can be represented as integrating a Dirac delta multiplied by $f$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: They parametrize the semi-circle $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ as the curve $\vec{C}(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))$, then they use the fact that $\int_C fds = \int_0^\{pi} f(C(t))*C'(t)dt$

Comment: what is the formula for semi circle parameterization?

Comment: @Basbas the parametrization is $C(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$, for $t \in [0,\pi]$.